# Unregistered Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I downloaded Sublime Text 3 on my MacBook Air; however, the text editor continues to have **UNREGISTERED** on the top right hand corner of the tab. As a result, I presume, I cannot save anything in the said text editor. How do I fix this?

[image: Sublime Window]

Comment: Try purchasing a license and see if that changes anything ...

Comment: You can use it without limit, if you want to remove the **UNREGISTERED** then buy a license.

Comment: There are plenty of free, open source options out there that won't nag you. Atom and VSCode come to mind. Sublime Text is a great editor, though. If you find it useful, register it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sublime Text is fully functional in it's unregistered evaluation mode with the exception that:

1. It reminds you every few saves to purchase it if you're going to use it for an extended purpose (i.e. it's not free to use forever, despite what many web pages and users claim)
2. You cannot turn off update checks at startup to gently remind you that as an unlicensed user, you should be running the most recent version.

The error that you're seeing isn't Sublime telling you that you can't save because it's unregistered, it's MacOS telling you that you can't save files to the root of the file system (`/`).

On Unix-like systems such as MacOS and Linux, non-administrative users aren't allowed to save files anywhere but their own home directories (and a few other places, like `/tmp`) unless you specifically set things up to allow it, because indiscriminate creation or editing of files in the wrong place can cause problems.

As such, if you pick a different folder (somewhere under `/Users/yourusername`) to save in, it will work as you expect.